# How to change exporting icon in Amcharts 5?

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts, amcharts5

I know in Amcharts 4, you could follow along with this to change the exporting icon: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/replacing-default-export-icon/

But, how is this same task done on Amcharts 5? It seems to be different.

Comment: related?: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/tutorials/adding-custom-buttons-to-exporting-menu/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a natively supported way to achieve this but did find a work around.

For my context I'm using Vue 3. In my onMounted event (once the chart has been created) I added this:

`document.getElementsByClassName('am5exporting-icon')[0].innerHTML = ' *custom img / svg* '`

Providing my desired SVG content as a string here did the trick. Would also work fine with a custom `<img>` tag I expect.